# Using for loop in rules and errors with shell split command

Tags: python, snakemake

I am a first time user of Snakemake and I am having trouble with some of my rules definition.

Here's the snakefile which I am running:

```
import os
import re

READS="r1 r2".split()
READ1=READS[0]
READ2=READS[1]
array=[]

#To get a list of filtered reads suffixes after running the rule split_reads
f_reads = os.listdir("./filtered_reads")
for i in range(len(f_reads)):
        mm = re.match(r'(.+-)([a-z][a-z])',f_reads[i])
        if mm:
                array.append(mm.group(2))

rule quality_filter:
        input:
                expand("data/{{sample}}_{read}.fq",read=READS)
        output:
               expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50.fq",read=READS)
        shell: """
                fastq_quality_filter -Q33 -q 20 -p 50 -i {input[0]} -o {output[0]}
                fastq_quality_filter -Q33 -q 20 -p 50 -i {input[1]} -o {output[1]}

        """



rule fastq_conversion:
        input:
                expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50.fq",read=READS)
        output:
                expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50.fasta",read=READS)
        shell: """
                fastq_to_fasta -Q33 -n -i {input[0]} -o {output[0]}
                fastq_to_fasta -Q33 -n -i {input[1]} -o {output[1]}
        """


rule fasta_temp:
        input:
                expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50.fasta",read=READS)
        output:
                expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50.fasta_temp",read=READS)

        shell: """
                awk '/>/{{temp=$0; getline; print temp "\\t" $0}}' {input[0]} | sed  's/\/1/ 1:N:0:8 /' | sort > {output[0]}
                awk '/>/{{temp=$0; getline; print temp "\\t" $0}}' {input[1]} | sed  's/\/2/ 2:N:0:8 /' | sort > {output[1]}
        """

rule filtered_join:
        input:
                expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50.fasta_temp",read=READS)
        output:
                expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50_filtered.fasta",read=READS)
        shell:"""
                join -j 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 {input[0]} {input[1]} | awk '{{print $1 " " $2 "\\n" $3}}' > {output[0]}
                join -j 1 -o 2.1 2.2 2.3 {input[0]} {input[1]} | awk '{{print $1 " " $2 "\\n" $3}}' > {output[1]}

        """

rule split_reads:
        input:
                expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50_filtered.fasta",read=READS)
        output:
                expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50_filtered.fasta-",read=READS)

        shell:"""
                split -l 3000 {input[0]} {output[0]}
                split -l 3000 {input[1]} {output[1]}

        """


rule run_igblast:
        input:
                expand("filtered_reads/{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50_filtered.fasta-",read=READS)
        output:

        run: """
                for i in range(len(array)):
                        shell("perl vpairhumanalysis-igblast-isotype_BDmod.pl {input[0]+array[i]} {input[1]+array[i]} human_barcodes.txt")

        """
```

==========

Error:

Error in job split_reads while creating output files filtered_reads/A_r1_q20p50_filtered.fasta-, filtered_reads/A_r2_q20p50_filtered.fasta-.
MissingOutputException in line 67 of /home/vagrant/snakemake-2/Snakefile-3:
Missing files after 30 seconds:
filtered_reads/A_r1_q20p50_filtered.fasta-
filtered_reads/A_r2_q20p50_filtered.fasta-
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message

=============

The files are split according to the split command but the program returns the above error at the end and does not execute the next rule.

Also, I have another query regarding the rule 'run_igblast'. So, after getting the files split, I need to run a perl script on the files obtained after the split command. The output from the perl script is actually a different file which doesn't have the name similar to the input files. What shall I do in this case where the input file doesn't match with the output file?  I am not sure whether the loop for all split files should be placed in the input or run sections of the run_igblast rule. I want the command in run_igblast in the following manner:

```
perl vpairhumanalysis-igblast-isotype_BDmod.pl A_r1_q20p50_filtered.fasta_aa A_r2_q20p50_filtered.fasta_aa human_barcodes.txt
```

Comment: The error means (as printed) that the file ` filtered_reads/A_r1_q20p50_filtered.fasta- filtered_reads/A_r2_q20p50_filtered.fasta` is not there after execution of the job. I suggest to check whether your command really creates the files it is supposed to create.

Comment: A general comment: since all your rules work on the two read files independently, there is no need to have two separate shell commands in each. Simply make `{read}` a wildcard instead of using the expands. Then, each job from those rules works on one of the two read files.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The files created by the rule 'split_reads' get suffixes aa, ab , ac and so on. The output files should be named in the following manner: A_r1_q20p50_filtered.fasta-aa, A_r1_q20p50_filtered.fasta-ab and likewise. So, for the output I think the filename is correct then - '{{sample}}_{read}_q20p50_filtered.fasta-'.

Comment: Please see my query related to 'run_igblast' rule stated above and provide your suggestion.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect your `array` variable will not be initialized properly, because its construction depends on a loop over the contents of `./filtered_reads`, which is used to store the output of some of your rules.